# Microservice pattern for delayed task processing

Tags: architecture, microservices

We have a conference call microservice that keeps a list of active calls in a documentdb table.  Every 15 minutes, I'd like to check this table for inactive calls and end them.  We are running N instances of this microservice.

Are there any common patterns out there for processing delayed tasks like this in a REST-full microservice?

I feel like I need to use a "Promise" but I don't know the best way to build that at the server.

I could write an external service that pings the conference call service once a minute.  That doesn't seem great.

I could use a queue but that doesn't seem great for a regular scheduled task like this.

I do have an event hub that I can publish and subscribe to but I would need to build something to maintain that list of promises and publish them.

I'm using .NET and Azure but I also need to run this OnPrem so I can't necessarily depend on something like Azure Durable Functions.

--Thanks

Comment: What is the reason that the call service cannot end the inactive call itself and update the active calls table (either directly or via queue)?

Comment: Since there are N instances running, they could all end the call and send N notifications.  Looking for a way to do this atomically.

Comment: But don't you have a single instance handle a single call (open socket connection etc)? Anyway if you want to do a scheduled task I would run a small script/program through the corresponding cluster service (e.g. in kubernetes you can have scheduled jobs)  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Comment: Thanks, I could do a cron job, and I may do that but it doesn't seem great to be polling once a minute.

Comment: On Azure in their messaging bus they give the functionality to send a time based command ,  which will execute after a given time , and i think they must have given the functionality to run command only at one instance